# How to change all cloned elements id's and name's the fastest way - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, clone

I have few bootstrap tabs that contain forms and I am cloning the original tab by iterating my object

```
 var clonedLayouts = [105, 208];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kL5n8/4/

The clone works perfect , the issue I have is that I would like to find the fastest way to 
change id and name attribute of each element in the new clone since they all have kept the original element id,names.

So instead of going trough each element and changing them like I did for tabs
does anyone wknow the fastest way for all of them to get and extra

```
original_name_or_id + newClone
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is an other solution:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/42gWf/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clonedLayouts = [105, 208];
    for(i=0;i<clonedLayouts.length;i++){
      $('<li id="mainbodyTab-itemid+'+clonedLayouts[i]+'" class=""> <a id="defaultmbtr-itemid+'+clonedLayouts[i]+'" href="#defaultmb-itemid+'+clonedLayouts[i]+'" data-toggle="tab">-itemid'+clonedLayouts[i]+'</a>').appendTo(".mainbodytabs")
      $("#defaultmb").clone().attr('id', 'defaultmb-itemid' + clonedLayouts[i]).removeClass('active').appendTo(".mainbodytabcont");
    }

});
</script>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: that is way to complicated and it does not answer the question. all names and id's from forms are still same as first one